# I can write but I can't read from google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-storage

I have a nextjs app that is using next-auth to handle authentication with google + I'm using `@google-cloud/storage` to write to my private bucket. This all works just fine but I'm not able to read any of the images from my app? I'm getting `403` errors when trying to read the files. I've allowed my service account, which is attached to my app via:

```
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
export const upload = async (req: IncomingMessage, userId: string) => {
  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: process.env.GCS_PROJECT_IT,
    credentials: {
      client_email: process.env.GCS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      private_key: process.env.GCS_PRIVATE_KEY
    }
  });
  const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GCS_BUCKET_NAME as string);
  const form = formidable();
  const { files } = await parseForm(form, req);
  const file = files.filepond as any;
  const { path } = file;
  const options = {
    destination: `products/${userId}/${file.name}`, // this url gets stored in postgres
  };
  await bucket.upload(path, options).catch(console.error);
}
```

to allow reading/writing to my bucket but I'm only able to write to it. I can see that the images are being successfully uploaded to cloud storage but I'm just denied access to read it. Am I missing a rule here?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect. We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the information you provide.

Comment: Post has been updated to include the rest of the upload code. The cloud storage url just gets saved to the DB and loaded when I fetch some data. So the URL is valid I just can't view it because of permissions.

Comment: You should show the code that **isn't** working the way you expect.  You mentioned that reads are failing, so that would be the thing to show or explain in detail.